# DbUpdateException - Exception when saving database changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am receiving the error:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

I have read around and the problem seems to be due to improperly defined foreign keys in the DB.

My code I am running:

```
foreach (Contact c in toDelete)
{
       DbContext.Contacts.Remove(c);
}

DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Intending to delete contacts that have been selected for deletion.

The Contact object looks as follows:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateJoined { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Group> Group { get; set; }
    public int? ImportId { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
```

And the relevant mapping in my context class is:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema:false)
    {

    }

    public virtual DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MessageDeliveryLog> MessageDeliveryLogs { get; set; }


    modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().HasMany(x => x.Contacts).WithMany(x => x.Messages);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasMany(x => x.Contacts).WithMany(x => x.Group);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().HasMany(x => x.Groups).WithMany(x => x.Messages);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().HasMany(x => x.Messages).WithMany(x => x.Contacts);
    modelBuilder.Entity<MessageDeliveryLog>().HasRequired(x => x.Contact);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ContactHistory>().HasRequired(x => x.Contact);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().HasRequired(x => x.Organisation);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().HasMany(x => x.Group).WithMany(x => x.Contacts);

base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I'm a little confused as to what I could be lacking. I have also tried the remove function on a context with lazy loading enabled and proxy creation disabled which did nothing.

I believe the answers are in my mapping but I'm not sure where, how do I fix this issue?

**Added**

I can create and update contacts absolutely fine.

Comment: `Contact` has 3 nav properties: `Organisation`, `Messages` and `Group` but does not have any foreign keys defined (even for some default convention to work). So in code configuring, you need some mapping (with Map() method) to specify the foreign keys. I guess your table may not even have any foreign key columns created?

Comment: Once you've ensured that you have foreign keys set up correctly in the DB you also need to tell entity framework which field you intend to use as the key. Either annotate the id fields with [Key] or use a mapping file to set up your keys there: this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

Comment: @StephenBrickner Thanks for the replies, and I'm sorry about the code I posted not being helpful. The relationships and keys are created by entity framework using the OnModelCreating method with the modelBuilder. The tables have foreign keys, so I'm confused why it won't remove my entities. Adding and updating contacts works completely fine

Comment: @Hopeless please see above